# How to get accurate percentiles for big data in PIG?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to find percentiles in PIG and for that I'm using `datafu-1.2.0.jar` package, but my answers are not matching. I found out that all the data is pushed to a single reducer per key so I think that's why it is not working for me (file is 10.5 GB). Is there a way to solve this problem without having to partition my data as in I want to find percentiles for entire record using group all?

Comment: Its good practice to group data by a key (provided you have fair distribution/varieties of keys in input data) and then pass each group to UDF. Thus you can achieve parallelism. It would be quick to solve the problem if you provide a code snippet where you are using the datafu package.

Comment: my code is like this:-    REGISTER datafu-1.2.0.jar;  define Quantile datafu.pig.stats.Quantile('0.0','0.5','1.0');   a= load 'file.csv' USING PigStorage (',') as (schema);  b= foreach (group b all)  GENERATE Quantile(variable_name);

Comment: The problem is you are doing group by all. Thus all the data is getting grouped in 1 bag and passed to Quantile UDF. This is the reason why its running in 1 reducer. Group on a key in your data. That might create more bags. Pass this new bag to UDF. It should be better performer.

Comment: I know this , but I want to calculate percentiles across a entire column and therefore I have to group it all together rather on a single key Can I do that?